# Generate a gradient from extrema of a float Image

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

As the title states, i need to generate a gradient from the lowest value to the highest value of a given float Image. This shall serve as a legend to the image.

my idea is to create an image and then fill every pixel of it with a value within the range of the extrema.
I am still not a Pro in Python, so any help would be nice.
What i got so far:

```
im = Image.open('path_to.tiff')
extrw=im.getextrema()
grad = Image.new('F', (10, 100))
pix = grad.load()
for i in range(grad.size[0]):    # for every pixel:
    for j in range(grad.size[1]):
        pixels[i,j] = (some_float)
```

As you can see i need to somehow use extrema to get the float values accordingly into the pixels to create a gradient.
it would be nice, if i could stay in the PIL library.

Thank you!

Comment: What sort of gradient? Linear? Radial? Which axis? Please be more precise.

Comment: Ah yes. Linear, Vertical

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research i found that this could be a linear function. all i had to to was to put the minimum, maximum and length into this mathematical form : y=m*x+b

with the help of a kollegue we figured: y(the pixel value)= ((minvalue-maxvalue)/h(heigth of the image))*index_of_pixel+maxvalue. in code form:

```
extw=im.getextrema()
grad_b = 10
grad = Image.new('F', (grad_b, im_h))
pix = grad.load()
for i in range(grad.size[0]):    # for every pixel:
    for j in range(grad.size[1]):
        pix[i,j] = (extw[0]-extw[1]/im_h)*j+extw[1]
```